# CSS transition for border is pushing the button down

Tags: html, css, button, transition

So I have a border transition on hover and on active for a circular button so the border increases in size.  However, the border expands downwards, pushing the button downward.  Is there any way to make it so the border expands evenly outward?  I've searched this site and others for solutions, and while there are similar questions, they don't answer this specifically.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<center><a class="btn" href="#"></a></center
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
  vertical-align: top;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0px solid red;
  transition: border-width 0.1s ease-in;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.btn:hover {
  border: 20px solid red;
}

.btn:focus {
  border: 75px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using border, you can generate a border effect by placing a `pseudoelement` behind the button, and transforming its scale on hover and focus as needed.

*also note that `<center>` is deprecated in HTML5. You can center content with CSS instead.

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: border-width 0.1s ease-in;
}

.btn:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .1s ease;
}

.btn:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.btn:focus:before {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: However, the border now goes _inside_ the button, and my goal is to get it to go outside the button.  The eventual goal is a circle menu where icons are on the outer border that appear on focus of button.

Comment: I've changed the initial colour from transparent to white, to match the background. Is that the effect you want?

Comment: It's close, but on focus, the border still goes inside of the button.  Also, the transition is still on Border-Width and not the color.

Comment: I've updated the answer using a different approach that I think might be more appropriate in your case. You can adjust the amount of scale as you need. If you'd prefer to transition with `px` on hover, you can update the `height`, `width` and coordinates of the `:before`.

Comment: This works perfectly now, I didn't think of using `:before`.